# send get request with id in redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have some list on the first page and I want to by click set Request to get single items by redux-saga but it's run before click and return undefined and not show the response of the first request of list. I want to pass some slug to the end of the request and return details of the item.

Cards.js

```
    SetSlugItems(Items){
   this.props.onFetchArticle(Items.slug)
}
render(){
    console.log('this.props.articles.articles',this.props.articles.articles)
    return (
            <ContainerContent>
                <ContentHolder>
                    <CardHolderStyled >
        {this.props.articles.articles&&this.props.articles.articles.map((Items,index)=>{
                            return(
                                <Link  to={{ pathname: '/singleArticle', state: { index:index} }}  >
                                    <CardItemStyled key={index} onClick={()=>this.SetSlugItems(Items)} >

                                    </CardItemStyled>
                                </Link>
                            )})}
                    </CardHolderStyled>
                    <SideBar/>
                </ContentHolder>
            </ContainerContent>
        );}}
```

Action.js

```
 function fetchArticleAction (slug) {
    return {
        type: GET_SINGLE_ARTICLE,
        slug
    };
}
function getArticleSuccessSingle (receiveArticleSingle) {
    return {
        type: GET_SINGLE_ARTICLE_SUCCESS,
        receiveArticleSingle
    };
}
function getArticleFailureSingle () {
    return {
        type: GET_SINGLE_ARTICLE_FAILURE
    };
}
```

Saga.js

```
function* getArticleSingle (action) {
    try {
        const receiveArticleSingle = yield call[fetchArticleSingle(action.slug)] ;
        yield put(getArticleSuccessSingle(receiveArticleSingle));
    } catch (err) {
        yield put(getArticleFailureSingle());
    }
}
const fetchArticleSingle = (slug) => {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/articles/'+slug, {
       method:'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
};
function* watchGetArticle () {
    yield takeEvery(GET_ARTICLE, getArticle);
    yield takeEvery(GET_SINGLE_ARTICLE, getArticleSingle);
}
```

and Reducer.js

```
import {
    GET_SINGLE_ARTICLE_SUCCESS,
    GET_SINGLE_ARTICLE_FAILURE
} from '../constants';
const initialStateSingle = [];
const SingleArticleReducer = (stateSlug = initialStateSingle, action={}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_SINGLE_ARTICLE_SUCCESS:
            return  action.receiveArticleSingle;
        case  GET_SINGLE_ARTICLE_FAILURE:
            return [];
        default:
            return stateSlug;

    }
};

export default SingleArticleReducer
```

Comment: A Codesandbox with a minimal example would help to see the problem. But I think dispatch of the action to redux is not happening. The `onClick` on `CardItemStyled` is probably not executed as you're having it inside of a `Link` tag. I would try to dispatch the action in `<Route render={()=> dispatch()}>` and check that the slug is available as route param - so no need to use `onClick`

Comment: I want to click on the card and active action in redux but in initial it's run not after the click. you mean my on click is problem? @AWolf

Comment: Yes, probably. I'm also not seeing `mapDispatchToProps`. It's needed so `onFetchArticle` action is passed to your component.

Comment: i have ```mapDispatchToProps``` and this its ``` const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return{
        onFetchArticle:(slug)=> dispatch(fetchArticleAction(slug))

    }
};``` @AWolf how to pass to redux-saga?

Comment: OK, `mapDispatchToProps` looks good. Have you checked that the action is dispatched e.g. console.log or use Redux-dev tools? You need to setup Redux-Saga by adding it as middleware and run your `rootSaga`. You could have a look at the following [repo](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/guppy/blob/master/src/store/index.js) to get an idea of the setup & also read the [redux saga tutorial](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
call[fetchArticleSingle(action.slug)]
```

This is accessing a property on the `call` function, and that property is `undefined`. Instead you'll want to call `call`, as in:

```
call(fetchArticleSingle, action.slug);
```